# File being simultaneously written, read and removed

Tags: file

I'm wondering if there is an mechanism that reads a file while it is being written and remove the content that has been read simultaneously. The purpose for doing this is because the file is stored in memory (ramdisk) and as the file size increases, we need to remove the part that has already being processed.

Thanks a lot!!!

PS: I'm using Linux and Java for this. :)

Comment: hArdware/System/Language?

Comment: You're describing a pipe... if it needs a name, `mkfifo`... but we don't even know what OS you're using.

Comment: In the same way a database could do it?

Answer (score 2):

Data cannot be removed from the beginning or middle of a file. Process the data using multiple files and erase them as they are consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from a file while it is being written to is no big deal, this is the purpose of every tail program, however deleting already read content of an opened file... I don't think it is possible.

You may want to think of a work around. For example you can have a number of files `{0,n}` with the same limit of bytes to write to. Start writing the `file_i` where `i` is the highest available number out of `{0,n}` and go up to `limit`. Reading starts from the lowest available `file_i`, reads up to `limit` and when done deletes the file just consumed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I do now. However, it seems a continuous processing is required, which means I cannot process a block of contents. Because it has the risk that the application may wait a long time to reach the file size limit

Answer (score 0):

We still haven't heard what OS our friend user2386567 is using, but as a counterpoint to the other answers declaring that it's impossible to delete data from the middle of a file, I'd like to point out that Linux has `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` for that exact purpose.

Comment: Exactly, I'm using Linux! I will check if the FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE works!